# Make a bottom up poem

Tags: code-golf, random

Based on the ["Pretty Ugly"](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/87/ef/ec/87efecc2e9b48e35b1b9943760ac23b6.jpg) poem.

Input consists of a number of stanzas (positive integer), and four arrays/lists of strings, called the "negatives", "negations", "positives", and "filler" sentences.

You must output a "pretty ugly" poem with the specified number of stanzas. A stanza consists of a negative, negation, positive and filler sentence, in that order. Finally, the poem must end with the string `(Now read bottom up)`.

In other words, the output must be a list of strings of the form `[negative, negation, positive, filler, negative, negation, positive, filler, negative, ..., "(Now read bottom up)"]`, with the `negative, negation, positive , filler` part repeated once per stanza.

Rules:

- The lines should be chosen at random from the lists
- Output can be in any format, as long as it's a comprehensible poem. Printing to STDOUT, returning a list of strings, returning a string with lines separated by commas, and so on are all allowed
- You may assume that the 4 lists are all non-empty, but not that they have the same length
- The number of stanzas can be zero. If so, the output is `(Now read bottom up)`
- Shortest program (in bytes) wins

Sample input:

```
n = 4

negatives = [
  "I am a terrible person",
  "Everything I do is useless",
  "I don't deserve to be loved",
  "I will never succeed at anything"
]

negations = [
  "It's foolish to believe that",
  "I don't think it's reasonable to say that",
  "I will never believe that",
  "No one can convince me into thinking that"
]

positives = [
  "I am beautiful inside and out",
  "The people around me love me",
  "I will succeed at my career",
  "I can be successful"
]

fillers = [
  "I just have to accept that",
  "After all, it's pretty clear",
  "So I think it's pretty obvious",
  "It will be clear if you think about it"
]
```

Sample output:

```
I don't deserve to be loved
I don't think it's reasonable to say that
I will succeed at my career
After all, it's pretty clear
I don't deserve to be loved
I don't think it's reasonable to say that
I can be successful
I just have to accept that
Everything I do is useless
No one can convince me into thinking that
I can be successful
So I think it's pretty obvious
I don't deserve to be loved
It's foolish to believe that
I am beautiful inside and out
I just have to accept that
(Now read bottom up)
```

Comment: I think some test cases would help make this more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear, but I added a sample input and output.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I'd recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges, although I think this is a pretty good first challenge. (To close voter(s): I don't see anything particularly unclear).

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms This challenge was sandboxed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>62</s> 61 bytes

*@randomdude999 pointed out a space I could remove to save a byte.*

```perl
sub f{(map{map$$_[rand@$_],@_}1..pop),"(Now read bottom up)"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZJNa9xADIbv/hXCLGQX3CUp5JJQ2B5yCLS5tD01ZZFtOZ5mPBrmw2EJ@et1NR6zMTEYDyPp1aNXtuT09TT5WEP3uh3Qvsq72Rx/OzTtYXP8Ux2Ob1f7vWW7q8rtA7@AI2yh5hB4gGh35dt0MPSEQY3k4Qtsy3vAARACOadqTWDJeTZlVZR3I7lT6JV5gntoGZSH6EmT9ymarsxFgJY8uZEgMNQEmkdqc/hFaQ2GRAR8bBqiFjAAmixZ7m6LYkFhs6CECw8ds1a@z3paUZLuMaxbJoFnUClbxhNaTOBS4PG0Sl4BfFR6YGBD0KCBhs2oTEMwECgjIrN6GnpOnjEte/XBsZowBtVFLUVetSSDtcBxVv/ZJxvZChQ6jhIYsjPyXaGtXBlOwuKIXA4nLjFzTvBempQFyCMsh04qZUMLyN/oA/SY7UfJtuE849dOdgqodZWtso5CkD6aUNokvaL8wbLalZ1LDtej4pjXHDKs4MyVoDo4cVyKsJaRpfTMV6QVdOyg2z6@/2jV4/um5Xy2U87LPNXn3e30j@2cMn36fr2/utxfyuGb8uHm5ldQ@j8)

A function which takes in the sets of statements as a reference to an array for each type of statement and the number of stanzas.  Returns an array of strings, one element for each line of the poem.

Comment: you can drop the space in `rand @$_` to save 1 byte

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <del>135</del> <del>118</del> 115 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(a,b):
 for _ in range(b):
  for x in a:shuffle(x);print x[0]
 print'(Now read bottom up)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVK7jttADOz1FQM1tgMVwZUXpEiR4pprks4wAkpLnTZZLYV96Oyvd7ha4yKkWoEcDmeGWm5pEv90v49BZgTyRh87LxLSp8bwiPFIXX96bjBKwC9YX0BvfNxqW/FaivQcpzyOjo/X05clWJ9wPX@@NNi@D8dXeUdgMuglJV2Rl9PhTviKc/sCmkFIHILtHWPhEMW3XdN@XzmoPuvf8AIjsBE5suMYS7eU/CHBcOSwMpKgZzhZ2dT2u3UOnpUEMQ8DswElkK@U7aVp@iogHaI6EWfjVFmc5UI4UdovKmN/YAtarahGKnJ1INJtB96t/Z/pVSCeMZDHIH61fmDMrPkpycZerG5gFTf8S6dnysmO2Sk0WsNqwkDyxvlzKpHJolIoSNbGXFPQdydol8B8UwWBOdR2UaPBbYAYdUmrhwVUgXko@J1jwkQ1Y1LYkj4sfRv1cCDnuprMEjglXeCYlL8QNe0P0fvt0ntgpF@t5HrLVFWqjm0SdsRN8mOIevWqox/CxuNZ/8pu6Mylezrd/wI)

13 for @Danis and 3 for @Arnauld cheers!

Comment: @Arnauld edited please see, now second parameter will take it

Comment: @Danis so nice of you

Comment: You should probably use `x[0]` instead of `x.pop()`. I think the number of stanzas can be higher than the number of available options, and re-using the same line several times is fine according to the spec.

Comment: Does `print choice(x)` work? Know your Python built-ins...

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZI/b9wwDMV3f4oHL3eXeigyBsjQoUOWLO3mGgVt0bVaWTT0x8l9@itlH1KjXmSJ5OOPT1quaRL/eBuff9wczb0hUNM/tcMkduDz@2WUgJ@wHu3n7qFH2b6XLXWf2tP5Vd4QmAx6SUlm5OVy6qox6G8gb3Sx8yIhPdwIz2jrF9AMQuIQbO8YC4covm6q@uvKQVms/4UXGIGNyJEdx1ii5cifEgxHDisjCXqGk5XNHn6zzsGziiDmYWA2oATyu2TdVVW/A6RT1CHE2TjtKs5yEZwoHRuVsj@wJVvnU0YquFoQ6XpIPrT9X@lVIJ4xkMcgfrV@YMys1qnIpl5G3ZIVbvjnTs@Ukx2z09RoDesQBpI3ze9TsUwWRaEgWQPz7oKuB6CDA/NVCQJz2MOFRo3bEmLUJnUF/ZTA3Al@55gw0e4xadqSPkb6MurFgZxrdmeWwClpA8ek@kWoqr@J3t/BvXuO9KuVvN9l2imVY6uEHXGVfC@iXmfV0g@w8uKc9cU5jOdWX2czNKZrHi9Plaqrn1v49hc)

Comment: (@Danis 91 bytes by removing the space between `in` and `[0]`)

Comment: The two spaces can be a tab for -1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `W`, 24 bytes

```
?(4(?℅)?_)`(λṠ ƛ□ ¢¼ up)
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=W&code=%3F%284%28%3F%E2%84%85%29%3F_%29%60%28%CE%BB%E1%B9%A0%20%C6%9B%E2%96%A1%20%C2%A2%C2%BC%20up%29&inputs=4%0A%5B%22I%20am%20a%20terrible%20person%22%2C%20%22Everything%20I%20do%20is%20useless%22%2C%20%22I%20don%27t%20deserve%20to%20be%20loved%22%2C%20%22I%20will%20never%20succeed%20at%20anything%22%5D%0A%5B%22It%27s%20foolish%20to%20believe%20that%22%2C%20%22I%20don%27t%20think%20it%27s%20reasonable%20to%20say%20that%22%2C%20%22I%20will%20never%20believe%20that%22%2C%20%22No%20one%20can%20convince%20me%20into%20thinking%20that%22%5D%0A%5B%22I%20am%20beautiful%20inside%20and%20out%22%2C%20%22The%20people%20around%20me%20love%20me%22%2C%20%22I%20will%20succeed%20at%20my%20career%22%2C%20%22I%20can%20be%20successful%22%5D%0A%5B%22I%20just%20have%20to%20accept%20that%22%2C%20%22After%20all%2C%20it%27s%20pretty%20clear%22%2C%20%22So%20I%20think%20it%27s%20pretty%20obvious%22%2C%20%22It%20will%20be%20clear%20if%20you%20think%20about%20it%22%5D&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
?(
```

Start a for loop, repeating `number of stanzas` times.

```
4(?℅)
```

From each list of possible lines, choose a random line.

```
?_)
```

Skip over the next input (which would be the number of stanzas again - input is cyclical in Vyxal, meaning that it loops around if EOI is reached [not applicable when using STDIN, only when passing input through command line])

```
`(λ≗ ƛΐ æ∺ up)`
```

Push the string "(Now read bottom up)`

```
-W flag
```

Wrap the entire stack into a list and implicitly output to STDOUT

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 57 bytes

Returns a list containing the items.

```ruby
->a,r{(1..r).map{a.map &:sample}<<"(Now read bottom up)"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLSuxAEN3PVxyy8AFxQNyJV3Dhwo0b3Q2zqCQ1N62drtiPSBC/faxODxLMIoHUqfMqn5r5@IF/OF7dU@2/Lq63W3@5HWj8ovzG2W2gYbT8fXdXXTzLJzxTh0ZilAFpvKy@j2OKAR@73a56Ag0gRPbeNJYxsg/iqnpTPU7s59gb9x9P6AQmIAW2HEKe5l/uPKLjwH5iREHDsDJxV8afxlo4VhKE1LbMHSiCXKGs9rVqx/OAg4g1oS8E1nDm6imuNfLGO0xGaxS1R9mpLgSaV@CV4l@mZ4E4RksOrbjJuJYxMIxTkoU9p1zAi6/cScOUojkkq6hgOlbrHSQtdK99Lkq0Y5CXpIOhZNfvyssq9zCruGf2ZZyNaF0LIAQVqTbQZ18jq7@lENFTaZUUMsbfJA8HPRXI2roUMnqOUcktk3Jnkk31InqxVWknjDSTkVSuF4tD9bBswhwwSzotUaM5dfVkSl3d7I8/)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>68</s> 62 bytes

```ruby
->a,r{r.times{puts a.map &:sample};puts"(Now read bottom up)"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVE9b9wwDN3vVzx4aFLAzdKtQQtk6JAlS7sdbqBtXq1EFh2JcmAE@e1XyjoURr0YEB/fF2Pu1ssrvuPy5Qe18T3eqZs4vc9ZE@huohmfviWaZs8f9@WxuX2SN0SmAZ2oyoQ8f24@Lq/H47F5BE0gKMfoOs@YOSYJTXtofi4cVx1d@INHDAKXkBN7TqlMy1O4UQycOC4MFXQMLwsPdfzmvEdgI0HKfc88gBQUKmVzak1bbxLOIt6lsRJ4x4VrJN1rlI0XuIK2FGaPilNbSLTuwDvF/5meBBIYPQX0EhYXesbEcMFINvaScgNvvkonHVNWd87eUMkNbNYHSN7ofo@lKLGGQVGyDaaa3f47L7vc02rikTnWcTFidW2AlEykOcC@U4ui/pyTYqTaKhlk1n9JHs52KpD3bS1kjqxq5J7JuAvJofkldrFdaVeMdIuTXK@n1aF52DbhzlglX5eos5y2ejVlrr6eLn8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 56 bytes

```perl6
{flat @_[^4].map(*.pick)xx^@_[4],"(Now read bottom up)"}
```

Takes the list arguments in a list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZI/T9xAEMV7f4onF@Eusq6IUBqERAoKGpqkQ0c0tsd4Yb1j7R/DCfHZL7P25bBwY8kz781v3nhkb38ehwO@dbg@vneWIm7@Pjxe7ncDjZvvu9E0L9u3t0f9eLmvys29vMIztaglRhmQxm35kQ1uHD9RNBMHXGNT3oEGECJ7b2rLGNkHcWVVlLcT@0PsjXvCHVqBCUiBLYeQq/mTu4hoObCfGFFQM6xM3C7lV2MtHKsJQmoa5hbKTG6xLLdXRfFJI@5EEy8COhFrQr9YWsPZvae4npo9XmByty6pwJTZVRDosGpeMXx1uheIYzTk0IibjGsYA8M4NZnd895z83/SUYL5klvNlKLpklVdMC3rei0kzQP@9DlMGZWLvCQtDEs@@l7RrbLRIQ15Zr@UM5pGOjeEoEPKAvooTqbpVKynOrE8pxDR03IHUsEYz5v@6vS4IGurJbDRc4w6yjLppGxZlL9Fb7wK9dQj9WQkLfeOC68SzUqYDgdJJxHVurVKz4jFLl@iE49u8/D5y1Wrg1erSKvzQvsKP7ZXx38)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 55 bytes

```
Tuples@#2~RandomChoice~#~Append~"(Now read bottom up)"&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHBSuxAELzvVzRZUB8EBPEqRMSDF3k8vYmHTqZjxjeZDjM9kWXJ/vras8nKLp4Gpquqq6p7lI56FNvgvr3bv6bBUazWN7t/6A33Dx3bhnbr3f0wkDe74uqZvyAQGqhZhHtIw5/iYv83WC/XVfv22HRcrcv1zftFVVXb1fa23K5gWzwB9oAgFIKtHcFAIbIvyhVA8ThS2Ehn/Qc8gWGwEVIk9RHnef70lwKGIoWRQBhqAscjmSPgyzoHnlQIYmoaIgMogH6WLaby4EEuI7TMzsZuFnGWsl6Hcr4ps/6DzXjNqkYxe1ZKxM0Z/GTvb7VnBvYEDXpo2I/WNwQ9gTbF84ac@ABf/OWOasIktk1OcdEa0hAGOC2Sr12ujvVIgIGTjvq5CX3PPJ200G/UQiAKR0A2pAUeIDHqqp/9nykKdDh3jDoe5CTPfavnA3SunKsZAomouCNctF9YL3hS3oLgerScjteU2aE6ODDBtrDhtNCw1qxKLqZpWk37bw)

Returns a list of stanzas, each of which is a list of strings, followed by the single string `"(Now read bottom up)"`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>59</strike> <strike>66</strike> 59 bytes

+7 bytes to fix the zero-stanza case AND -2 bytes after fixing it, thanks to @mazzy; additional 5 bytes cut by iterating on that 2 byte save

```powershell
param($a,$b),1*$a|%{$b|%{$_|random}}
"(Now read bottom up)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZI/b9wwDMV3f4oHw23uAi8FugZohw5ZsjR7QZ/pWKksGvrjwyG5z36lrPTOaBcLFsnHHx81y5F9GNnaSzM8vF1m8jTtGmqbbt9@uW/o/dNb0@XPr3dPrpfpfK7q3ZMc4Zl6dBKjTEjzvr6cq6pxeMDXfPILRbNw0P9vu6p@BE0gRPbedJYxa1dxdVvVPxb2pzga94JH9AITkAJbDiFH85W7i@g5sF8YUdAxrCzcl/DRWAvHKoKQDgfmHhRBrkjW1f4KI@4KE@8CBhFrwlgUreEsPlLcNs0Sv2Fytg6rvJTRtSDQaZO8QfhX6UkgjnEgh4O4xbgDY2IYpyKreh57TV5BZwnmP9c6phTNkKyWBdOzDtdD0qr/PGYrZVYs8pI0MBV39NzAbZyZTkrjmX0JZzI1dE0IQZsUkEGrdENXjNcUIkYqCyDNneN1xu@DbhVkbVusmj3HqF0s09rkp@hiN1Z@xKVbjKSy5FgwFWStghlwkvRRRJ0Oq6Ur2edmgD6y2/tqb9ttb/61fye4/AE)

Comment: nice. there is the rule 3 `The number of stanzas can be zero. If so, the output is (Now read bottom up)`

Comment: @mazzy Thanks, missed that one! Fixed.

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZLPTsMwDMbvfQqvKrChaoIHmAQHDly4wB25rUsDaVzlT6eJ7dmH04ytgkujxvbnnz9n4C1Z15HWx6LdfB8HtNgvCyyLanW/Xhd4u1gUuL/6Lqr4ed9bNA33h0OWL194C5awgYq95x7CsMqPhywrDGzgLp70gV6N5OT/YZnlz4A9IHiyVlWaYJDWbPIyy59GsjvfKfMBz9AwKAfBkSbnYjRemRsPDTmyI4FnqAg0j9Sk8FZpDYZEBFyoa6IG0AOaJJlnqzMMmzOMv3HQMmvluqSoFUXxDv28aZT4AhWzZVjhxYguBQ53s@QZwl@lFwY2BDUaqNmMytQEPYEyIjKpx7Gn5Al0YKf@uVYRBq/aoKXMqYZkuAY4TPpvXbSSB8FCy0ECfXJHzhnczJl@JzSWyKZwJBNDpwTnpEkCaaVKNnTG@AzOQ4dpASi5gz/P@NjKVgG1LpNVgyXvpYsmnJq8six2ZuUpztWoOKQl@4QpIFMVqBZ2HE5FWMmwUjqRXRctyCO7vK/yst3y4l/5O8HxBw "PowerShell – Try It Online") ?

Comment: @mazzy thanks! Got it back down to 59 with that idea

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 63 bytes

```r
function(n,l)c(l[sample(4,4*n,T)+0:3*4],"(Now read bottom up)")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZI/b5xAEMV7PsUTjcGhiJSrLF3hIoUbN3EXpRhgMJssO2j/YN2nv8wCJ3GyRbES@2beb96sv87C0/k6JNdFI65yja27yv4ONM2Wq1NzenTNW/3t@9OPx9Ofpqxe5QOeqUcrMcqENNdlfbXnrjWurwrH7xTNwgFndFUBlC@gCYTI3pvWMmb2QVzZ5LufC/tLHI17xwt6gQlIgS2HsN3nn@4houfAfmFEQcuwsnB/E3wYa@FYGyGkrmPuQRHktrZlUTfFDiXuABUfAgYRa8K4dbWGs8FI8d46t/kHk/U6tpJTHkJLAl3u5AeQz91eBeIYHTl04hbjOsbEME4brQ45glW@As8SzBcptkwpmiFZLQymZx2zh6Td423M4YquDeQl6dW0ZaXnHeQhp@miTJ7Z3wSZUCNeJSGo1QY0aJ3u7YDzN4WIkbalkKrneJj3edB9g6xttuhmzzGql2XarX6JrvwQ7q6QdjGSbuuPG7ACrZUwAy6S9jJqdXQtVkL9ivyQ9b3a@vof)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

Expects `([a0,a1,a2,a3])(n)`.

```javascript
a=>g=n=>n?a.map(a=>a.sort(_=>Math.random()-.5)[0]).join`
`+`
`+g(n-1):"(Now read bottom up)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZJPi5xAEMXvforCyypxJIHkEnCWHHLYQ/aS3IYhW2qpPWm7pP@4zKefVNvDICuIaNd79atXXnBF11m1@IPhnm5Dc8PmODamOZpnrGdcCnnH2rH1xd/m@Av9VFs0Pc9Feai/lafP57K@sDJv2duneI@FOXwpv@fFK7@DJeyhZe95hrCU@c3QiF6t5KCBU/4COAOCJ2tVqwkWso5NXmX5z5Xs1U/KjPACPYNyEBxpci6exk/myUNPjuxK4BlaAs0r9en4XWkNhsQEXOg6oh7QA5pkmZ@zLIGwuYP4JwcDs1ZuSm5aUTSe0O8bRvk/ULFaRhNWjNgicHjdFe/af3R6ZWBD0KGBjs2qTEcwEygjJpt7HHkrFsiFnfqQVksYvBqCFolTPclQPXDYvP9MMUJeBAktBzmYUyry3IHtEpmvQmKJbDqOVBLkVuCcNIkQg2hkL3eES3AeJkyho9Qt/jHbj0E2Cah1lSJaLHkvHTShNAC5svw3y0J3Md5ruF0Vh7RcnzAFZFOCGuDK4S7CVoYVaSSTAB1rqjWPxVCcHv9WBY/tVvDIsIL7JOey@FqWt/8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
ẋX€“ÐƇḶc⁻F¢nḲỵƝḣ»ṭ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVG7TsNAEOzzFSs3aVLyAxQgpaGBAhSlWNsbfOFyF93DyB3QUNDwAdBAQQMNEiiQLpHyH86PmD1fQBZuTvLMzszOTknKqmnq77vT7c3r9uphfb@5rRef2fZ6ebh6UvXivV5@bB7rxfNqWX@9NeuXs6YZjZIh4AwQHBkjUkkwJ2O1Sga95KAkU7lCqHMYQq5BWPCWJFkb0PBL9R3kZMmUBE5DSiB1SXmEL4WUoIhFwPosI8oBHaCKksl40GNz17cw0VoKW0QFKSiIFei6JmHkAkRgG0LOhyEqD1isOuSO5X@lIw1aEWSoINOqFCojmBEIxSKtelizJcdgoZWU0Dsx8ZJpVuTE4XPQvtU7KUJVes4x0GjPwCxuz28nTGfzWcXuhshEOCThwlqCtWzyazz11kGBsVJkdO7@ttif8J0ApRzEMuaGnGNdSciywF8vOdZ8rk5hO45OS6F9PJ2L4di@nQQxgUr73RCmvCKPJuNxs/cD)

Takes a list of the four lists as the first argument and the number of stanzas as the second argument. Returns a list of strings.

### Explanation

```
ẋX€“ÐƇḶc⁻F¢nḲỵƝḣ»ṭ   Main dyadic link
ẋ                    Cycle the list n times
 X                   Choose a random item
  €                    from each sublist
                 ṭ   Tack (append)
   “ÐƇḶc⁻F¢nḲỵƝḣ»    "(Now read bottom up)"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
и€Ω“ow‚Ø—è€¾)“„(Nìª
```

First input is the amount of stanzas, second a list of lists of sentences.
Output is a list of strings.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XVG7TsNAEOz5ipWbgJSKP6CgSJMGuijF2t7gg/NtdA9H6SK@gQIhRA0oH4CERJH0iG/wj5i9c1AsqpN2Zmdm59hhrqjrfj7a@@33W7t55lW7edo/tpuH/avMdl9nMmw3L6fT/Xb33u0@u/OT2SybANaA4MlalWuCJVnHJhtnlw3Zta@UuYEJlAzKQXCkyTkB48SMPJTkyDYEniEn0NxQmdCV0hoMiQS4UBREJaAHNL1gNh@LsR85WDBr5ap@XyuKUhX6gUNcuAMVyZZQomFMKXyH6yN34PdPZ8rAhqBAAwWbRpmCoCZQRiSSdjwwcVOo2EZOGLxaBC0sp0qS3CVwiGrXVWyIlxIBLQeZ1/3Z8h6DDE6u12JtiWxCYwrpKeHOicPB9DY4DxX2RaKAS/@X/2IhXwOo9bgvYWnJexHVhFHziuV3Bh0dYM4bxSH9lO8ziW3aAbWANYfDDuZyl2xm8/kv) (the `»` in the footer joins by newlines; feel free to remove it to see the actual list-output).

**Explanation:**

```python
и                    # Repeat the second (implicit) list of lists of strings input the
                     # first (implicit) integer-input amount of times as list
 €                   # Map over each inner list:
  Ω                  #  And take a random string from the list
   “ow‚Ø—è€¾)“       # Push dictionary string "ow read bottom up)"
              „(N    # Push string "(N"
                 ì   # Prepend it at the front "(Now read bottom up)"
                  ª  # And append it to the list of sentences
                     # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“ow‚Ø—è€¾)“` is `"ow read bottom up)"`.

Comment: Huh, you have the same problem that I did where the leading `(N` defeats string compression.

Comment: @Neil Yeah, 05AB1E has four different dictionary compressions: [lowercase with spaces; lowercase without spaces; titlecase with spaces; and uppercase with spaces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210). Although there is a sentence capitalization builtin which [works correctly on the lowercase string](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fSSMvv1yhKDUxRSEpv6QkP1ehtEBTSe/Qqv//AQ) and could have been used, [the lowercase compressed string with spaces adds a space between the `(n` unfortunately](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMcjUdNaw5PftQw6/CMRw1TDq8Acg/t0wRK6B1a9f8/AA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
Ｅ⊗⊗θ‽§ηι(N” &？t]₂➙υ/εT§¬+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVG7jtswEOz1FQM1JwNKly7VAUnhIofgks5wsRLXEROKq@NDF3@9sjQNRwgbQtrZeXGcKIxCbtu@BetT95WW7rPkwbF53G@HQ49X8kbm7jkdveE/3dTDHvR8aupe2720/z7kHYHJYJCUZEZeDjrcttPH/nRq2iNoBiFxCFYFsHCI4tu@ab@sHK5psv4njjACG5EjO46xTMsv/5RgOHJYGUkwMJysbOr43ToHz0qCmMeR2YASyFfKtjn3RT09RVxEnI1TpXCWC9tEaa9Sdn7DFrRmUYNUvOpCpOsOvNP8n@lFIJ4xkscofrV@ZMwMbUgqe8l5A9@dlV4GppzsJTvFRWtY7RtIvhH@mEpZsqgPCpJ1MNf8eu/c7LLPV5UPzKGOixWt7AaIUUUeyr9yTJiotko6XtIjx/NFnwrkXF/rWAKnpMSOSXmhp2m/i77YrrI7RobVSq6vl6o71b9twl5wlXxfokEz6qoaOp@3D6v7Cw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explantion:

```
   θ            Number of stanzas
  ⊗             Doubled
 ⊗              Redoubled
Ｅ               Map over implicit range
      η         Array of array of phrases
     §          Cyclically indexed by
       ι        Current index
    ‽           Choose random phrase
                Implicitly output on separate lines
(N              Output literal string `(N`
” &？t]₂➙υ/εT§¬+ Output compressed string `ow read bottom up)`
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>124</s> 123 bytes

```php
function($a,$n){for(;$n--;)$r=array_merge(array_map(fn($b)=>$b[array_rand($b)],$a),$r??['(Now read bottom up)']);return$r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZJNb9swDIbv@RVEICA24N5287Jghx166aW9BUFB23SsTRYFfbgIhv32jLaMxqgvFkTy5cOXcoO7fz@5we1Uf7z3ybZRsy0UVsqWf3v2Ra3s01NdKn9E7/H2PpK/UrGe0RW9ZDfl8YdqzvnSo@3mq0ulsKyUP53Oh@KFP8ATdtBwjDxCcuXhUtaeYvJW@frfvd7tlKUrRj1RgCOc98@AIyBE8l43hsCRD2z31W7/ayJ/i4O2V3iGjkEHSIEMhTBH5yt7iNBRID8RRIaGwPBEXQ5/aGPAkohASG1L1AFGQJsl95cHCtsVJR4C9MxGhyHrGU2z9IBx23IW@AN6zpZphRZncCkIeNskbwC@Kr0wsCVo0ULLdtK2JRgJtBWRRX0eekleMB0H/cWxhjBF3ScjRUF3JIN1wGlRfxtmG9kJFHpOEhizM/LfoG1cGW/C4ol8Ds9cYuaSEII0yRi9VMl2VojfKUQYMFuPkuni53w/e9knoDFVtsnJE4jSwxBKC5Bvt39lWevGyjWHm0lzyiuOGVRQlkrQPdw4rUXYyLhSurBN6N@7NLpC9cX58cIqeKxYzp8@ynkd5lLBt7Ks7/8B)

One time again PHP is suboptimal here, because of the way you can't really use loops or recursion in arrow functions. For reference, [my attempt with recursion](https://tio.run/##XZJNb9swDIbv@RVEYCA24B0G7LQsLXrooZdetlsQFLRNx9pkUdCHC2PYb88oy2iM5uAIIvny4UvZwd5@PFr59tG0QbGBviywLkxduNP5UL7yOzjCDhoOgUeItjpcqr@OQnQGCvO4pn/5WqNzOL@N5K5Urme0ZW/KoqlOD0VzzpcOTZeuLnWBlXSpqu@FO/67HXe7wtAVg5rIwwnO@xfAERACOacaTWDJeTb7erd/nsjNYVDmCi/QMSgP0ZMm71M0XZlDgI48uYkgMDQEmifqcvhdaQ2GRAR8bFuiDjAAmiy5v9xR2Kwo4eChZ9bKD1lPK0rSA4ZtyyTwB1TKFteEFhO4FHicN8kbgM9KrwxsCFo00LKZlGkJRgJlRGRRT0MvyQumZa8@OdYQxqD6qKXIq45ksA44Luq/hmQjW4FCx1ECY3ZG/jdoG1fGWVgckcvhxCVmLgneS5OM0UuVbGeF@B19gAGz9SiZNnzM99TLPgG1rrNNVp5SkB6aUFqA/Hb7nyxr3Vi55nAzKY55xSGDCspSCaqHmeNahI2MK6UL24TurYujvMTyfH9gNdw3LOcPG@W8znKp4VtVHW//AQ) is 4 bytes longer.

Takes an array of arrays of lines and an integer as input, returns an array of lines

EDIT: saved  byte by removing the space after `return`

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 50 bytes

```
L$`^\d+
*$'
"¶¶"%G@`.
¶¶
¶
$
¶(Now read bottom up)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFLTsMwEN37FCNUVD4SEhIHgAVClVA3sESok2RKDI4nssepcrEeoBcL47hFJQvnM@87CSTW4/00vS42nx/NrblZLM3FYX/YX1y@PG7uTH7Uwyz0uFrzDgJhAxWLcAepv56mB7MC7ABBKARbOYKeQmRvngcKo7TWf8EKGgYbIUVyFKPJ734p0FCkMBAIQ0XgeKBGZzvrHHhSOsRU10QNoAD6ImbMSpYRtszOxrZQnaWs0qL8SWfsD9gM1ciaB3M0RUccT8gzo38aawb2BDV6qNkP1tcEHYH1Sp91c6cZWbpXhEnsNjmFRNuQZm2Ak5j3Nm@De3XGwEm/dqWm3k/@ZxW7UT0DUdBZNtedzNMYVTt7faco0GLZGOqkl5LjaavbB1S5uXEfSETFHGEAvcwb6z84W8kRwNVgOen/kJJFDQvHbmHkdGRgpV2UZ34B) Each array of strings must end with a blank marker line. Explanation:

```
L$`^\d+
*$'
```

Repeat the arrays according to the number of stanzas.

```
"¶¶"%G@`.
```

Keep a random line from each array.

```
¶¶
¶
```

Join the arrays together.

```
$
¶(Now read bottom up)
```

Append the specified string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[*map(choice,a*b),'(Now read bottom up)']
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZI7b9wwEIR7/YqBmntAldMZcJEihRs3SXe@YiWuIsYUV@BDxv36y1I8OELUUNDOzn471HJLk/hv9/Hl/e5o7g2Buv75cp5pOQ6T2IE7Oven7nB8k08EJoNeUpIZeTkdrs0Y9DWQN3rYeZGQznfCCy7tK2gGIXEItneMhUMU33ZN@2PloHOt/41XGIGNyJEdx1iq5ZM/JBiOHFZGEvQMJyubWv60zsGzmiDmYWA2oATy1bK9Nk1fAdIhYhRxNk7VxVkuhhOl/aDS9gFb1LqfMlLB1YZIt514N/Z/pzeBeMZAHoP41fqBMTOsV5PNvay6iRVu@JdOz5STHbNTabSGdQkDyZvnr6lEJouiUJCshbmmoOcOaJfAfFOCwBxqudBocJsgRh3SNtBHCcyD4E@OCRPVjEllS/pa6fuoFwdyrqvJLIFT0gGOSf2LUdP@FL2/XXoPjfSrlVzvMlVK5dg6YUfcJD@aqNddtfULbJQAZ31JDuPxon9iN3Tm2j2dnht11zyPpXy6/wU)

Inspired by @Danis's comment on @Wasif Hasan's Python 2 answer. Input is the same format as both of those (first argument: list of 4 lists of strings, 2nd argument: number of stanzas)

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 122 bytes

```
Randomize:n=n-1
For i=0 to n
For Each x in Array(a,b,c,d)
WSH.Echo x(Int(4*Rnd))
Next
Next
WSH.Echo "(Now read bottom up)"
```

Header

```
a = Array("I am a terrible person","Everything I do is useless","I don't deserve to be loved","I will never succeed at anything")
b = Array("It's foolish to believe that","I don't think it's reasonable to say that","I will never believe that","No one can convince me into thinking that")
c = Array("I am beautiful inside and out","The people around me love me","I will succeed at my career","I can be successful")
d = Array("I just have to accept that","After all, it's pretty clear","So I think it's pretty obvious","It will be clear if you think about it")
n=4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>35</s> 20 bytes

```
:z!İπ*⁰²¨(ηøṘΔż₀Tüp)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVG7TsNAEPyVxU0ApYCWjoIiDQ3pohRre42PnO@sexiZKvANFHwCZUQDSKkSaMM3wI@YvXNQIqqTbmZnZmdLb2ddd3Z38LH4mh//3C9WL6vnw83r@u37/Wnz@Ln8eZiP18v6qOu6ySQZAVaA4MgYkUqCmozVKhkmFw2Z1pVCXcMIcg3CgrckyVoGw48aOMjJkmkInIaUQOqG8ojeCilBEUuA9VlGlAM6QNULJtMhG7uBhUJrKWzZz0tBQapEt@cQBmYgAtkQcjQMKZlvsd1x9/z@6Vxq0IogQwWZVo1QGUFFIBRLRO2wYOTGUKGNlNA7UXjJLCty4tw5aB/UxmVoSNccAY32/F/1a/O7C7K3ctWytSEyEQ0puKeIW8sOW9Mbbx2U2BeJDNbuL/95wacBlHLYl1Abco5FJWHQvNJ8nb2OtrBOG6F9vJTrM7FtnAFRQKv9dgZT3osnk@m0Oz35BQ)

[Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) is completely deterministic, and has no random number generator.  So, on the face of it, "anything involving randomness ... can't be answered in [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) without considerable extra effort or rule-bending"(1).

However, the constraint that 'lines should be chosen at random' seems (to me) to be sufficiently relaxed that we can elect to choose the lines of each stanza using a random (stanza-to-stanza) distribution, even if this is not re-randomized between runs of our program (so sequential runs will output the same 'random' poem (2)).

Some googling indicates that the digits of Pi have been shown to be 'random' (in a certain statistical sense), if a set of constraints about the distribution of chaotic sequences holds true (3).  Although this conjecture is still unproven, it suggests that we can use the digits of Pi as a random sequence, until proven otherwise.

So:

```
:z!İπ*⁰²¨(ηøṘΔż₀Tüp)    # Program with arg1=number of stanzas,
                        # arg2=list of lists of lines:
                                    
     *⁰²                # repeat the list of lists of lines arg1 times,
 z!İπ                   # and, for each list, select the line at the index
                        # given by the next digit of pi 
                        # (wrapping around the end of the list if there are
                        # <10 elements, and ignoring any lines beyond the
                        # tenth),
:       ¨(ηøṘΔż₀Tüp)    # and finally append the compressed string:
                        # "(Now read bottom up)"
```

(1) Credit: Zgarb's [description](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/19286/5) of [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) caveats in its nomination for 'language of the month'.
(2) If you don't like successive runs outputting the same random poem, we can offset the digit of Pi at which to start, using a user-provided 'random seed' in arg 3, for [2 more bytes](https://tio.run/##XVG7TsNAEPyVxU0ApQDR0VFQpKEhXZTibG/wkfOddQ8jUyUU/AAUfAJlhJAAKVUCbfgG/CNm7xwUi@qkm9mZ2dnMmWnTnN7u1fcP9XzxufieHa5e6vnr6nl/87Z@//l42jx@Leu72XC9LA6aphmNogGwHBhY1JrHAqFAbZSM@tF5ibqyGZdXMIBUATfgDAo0hkD/I3sWUjSoSwSrIEYQqsQ0oDdcCJBIEmBckiCmwCww2QpG4z4Z256BiVKCm6ydFxy9VMZsx8EPTIF7skZG0ZhPSXzDqh234/dP50KBkggJk5AoWXKZIOQIXJJE0PYLBm4I5duIkTnLJ04Qy/AUKXcKynm1YeYbUgVFYFo5@s/btendBemsnFdkrRF1QH0K6ingxpDD1vTaGQsZa4tkBBb2L//ZhE4DTIh@W0Kh0VoSFci85qWi63Q62sIqLrly4VK2zUS2YQb4BCrltjMspr1oMhqPm@Oj5uQX).
(3) https://www.nersc.gov/news-publications/nersc-news/science-news/2001/are-the-digits-of-pi-random/

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 57 bytes

```julia
f(n,l)=n<1 ? "(Now read bottom up)" : [rand.(l);f(n-1,l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZK9bttAEIR7PcWAjUWAMSAgVRLDSJHCjRu7E1QsyaV5zvGWuB86enplj6RkCa6I483sfjt778ka2v07nbqtq2z54H7t8Ihi@ywf8EwtaolRBqSxLPADe0@uvd/a8qfqv@3UcTg5POD7ZuP4jaKZOOhxvwGKJ9AAQmTvTW0ZI/sgrqjy3Z@J/TH2xr3hCa3ABKTAlkNY7vNPdxfRcmA/MaKgZliZuD0LPoy1cKyFEFLTMLegCHJL2WJzOCOJ@0SKdwGdiDWhX2paw7l8T/G2cS7yFybrNQblpjyCWgIdb@RXGF@rPQvEMRpyaMRNxjWMgWGcFpo75ABmecYdJZivCdZMKZouWbUF07KO2ELS2uG1z8HKqHDkJenVsOSk3xvEq4yGoxJ5Zn8WZD6Nd5aEoK1mnE5turJPmPcUInpa1kGqHePVrL873TTI2mqJbfQco3ayTGujF9FlXwW7KqSejKTz4uOCqzizE6bDUdJqo1oHV3PmG73GaN39Nr/c/eX1VZelV5c8q3WUQ1me/gM)

output is a list of strings